# Probabilities and Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Good day! Please check my answers. Here is the problem: Let $ X,Y, Z$ have joint pdf $f(x,y,z) = \frac23 (x+y+z), 0<x<1, 0<y<1,0<z<1,$ zero elsewhere.
Find the marginal probability density functions.$$ f_x(x) = \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1\frac23 (x+y+z) \ dy \ dz = \frac{2x+3} 3, 0<x<1$$ $$f_y(y) = \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1\frac23 (x+y+z) \ dx \ dz = \frac{2y+3} 3, 0<y<1$$ $$f_z(z) = \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1\frac23 (x+y+z) \ dx \ dy = \frac{2z+3} 3, 0<y<1 $$$P(0<X<\frac12,0<Y<\frac12,0<Z<\frac12)= \int\limits_0^\frac12\int\limits_0^\frac12 \int\limits_0^\frac12\frac23 (x+y+z) \ dx \ dy \ dz=\frac1{12}$How about this one. How will I answer this one? Compute for $P(0<X<\frac12)=P( 0<Y<\frac12)=P(0<Z<\frac12)$ For the conditional expectation of $E(X^2YZ+3XY^4Z^2)= E(X^2YZ)+3E(XY^4Z^2)= \int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1 (x^2yz)\frac23 (x+y+z)+ 3\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1 (xy^4z^2)\frac23 (x+y+z) \ dx \ dy \ dz= \frac{574}{2160} $

Comment: Why do you post twice the same question?

Comment: I am sorry,I am a little bit sleepy

Comment: Being sleepy makes that you repost the same question after a few minutes? Are you kidding us?

Comment: Sorry, I am editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your solution is not correct. The integrals are 
$f_{x}(x)=\int^{1}_{0} \int^{1}_{0} \frac{2}{3}(x + y +z) dydz = \frac{2x+2}{3}, x \in (0;1)$

and symetrically the second and the third double-integrals. What you got are even not densities because integrals of them is not 1 in any case. You can compute these double-integral iteratelly by using Fubini's Theorem.

Your idea how to compute $P(X < \frac{1}{2}, Y < \frac{1}{2}, Z < \frac{1}{2})$ is good but you did not compute the triple-integral correctly. It is

$\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{0} \int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{0} \int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{0} \frac{2}{3}(x + y + z) dxdydz = \frac{1}{16}$.

You can also compute it by using Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: Yes, thanks.. How about this one. This one is related to the previous question and I do not even know to begin with $$P(0<X<\frac12)=P( 0<Y<\frac12)=P(0<Z<\frac12)$$

Comment: Thanks yes, I reviewed it.. how about this one,$P(0<X<\frac12)=P( 0<Y<\frac12)=P(0<Z<\frac12)$

Comment: I do not understand the assigment. Do you want to prove the equality $P(0 < X < \frac{1}{2}) = P(0 < Y < \frac{1}{2}) = P(0 < Z < \frac{1}{2})$? If so, you can simply say that random variables X, Y, Z have identical densities and thus $P(X \in S) = P(Y \in S) = P(Z \in S)$ for each $S \subseteq R$.

Comment: I was instructed to compute... I am wondering if it is the same with the previous one which is 1/16 because the densities are dependent.

Comment: Probably, you were instructed to compute $P(0 < X < \frac{1}{2}, 0 < Y < \frac{1}{2}, 0 < Z < \frac{1}{2}$ which is $\frac{1}{16}$. Any equations cannot be \emph{computed}. Equations are just given facts. You can only ask, whether the equations are correct or not.

Comment: ah okay. thanks =)

Comment: so this means that I have to integrate each probabilities by their marginal pdf then prove if the three are equal?